# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist:

Tags: python, django

I have a python program that uses django and it generates the error django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist. I made a sample of code to illustrate my problem. I created two files a test_file.py and HelloTemplate.txt, located in the same directory C:\Games\Game1.

```
#file name: test_file.py
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(DEBUG=True,TEMPLATE_DIRS=('.', ))
#I also tried TEMPLATE_DIRS=('C:\Games\Game1', ), didn't solve the problem

import sys


def main():
    myTemplate = get_template("HelloTemplate.txt")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The second file is a txt file with a line Hello as fellow:
filename: HelloTemplate.txt
Hello Template

Here's the error that I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_file.py", line 17, in <module>
   main()
File "test_file.py", line 13, in main
   myTemplate = get_template("HelloTemplate.txt")
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 25, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: HelloTemplate.txt
```

Thanks for your help to fix this error.

Comment: What version of django are you using?  The reason I ask is that TEMPLATE_DIRS was deprecated and is no longer available in 1.10.

Comment: The command line "python -m django --version" gives 1.10.4.

Comment: When I comment out the setting of the TEMPLATE_DIRS, I get the error:   File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__
init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATES, but se
ttings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANG
O_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You are new to Django aren't you? Why don't you follow the tutorial? Using `settings.configure()` is not an everyday command. Try to do things the normal way first before attempting edge case stuff. Anyway, the thing is you need to define a `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: Yes I am very new to Django. I am just trying to run a code of someone else, this code is supposed to work, I installed the required version of python/django for it I am getting the error. I wouldn't mind to replace setting.configure() with something simpler, how should I do it? Thanks.

Comment: How to add TEMPLATES setting. I tried TEMPLATES = ['C:\Folder\mytemplates'] and used  settings.configure(DEBUG=True,TEMPLATES) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `get_template` searches the file's concrete path which you define in the django project `settings.py`.

Comment: I didn't create a file settings.py for this, should I create one or it is part of django? Here's the location of my django folder C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5\Lib\site-packages\django\

Comment: If you want to use get_template() as method in simple python module then it will not work. Because get_template search file into definition path .

Comment: Are you suggestims to add use TEMPLATES = ['C:\Games\Game1'] to replace TEMPLATE_DIRS ? I would appreciate more details how to implement this. Thanks

Comment: I guess this method will not work without django project creating

Comment: what do you mean by "without django project creating". Thanks.

Comment: At first you need create django project